# Free software (online is better) to divide large numbers?

Tags: soft-question, math-software

This may be a strange request, but I need to divide the number

$$\begin{align}
906962317013510660172065292089122190105\\032616616408866290429399148061610399285\\5701624463727487162247889904330833818\\932916941082247238731419301804839603756
\end{align}
$$

By
$$
\begin{align}
26844628193432396109627227465177\\02183312396780798128148958789411455\\8469448102682070257837402824170487
\end{align}
$$

I couldn't do it with Wolfram, and I don't know any other free software which could do this, does anyone know?

If anyone's interested, I needed this to decrypt some files encrypted with RSA.

Comment: Have you tried python? or sage?

Comment: I have go-pari and sage at home. Free, but one does need to install.

Comment: @MichaelBurr You mean the programming language? The only programming language I know is C and the variables there can't hold numbers as large.

Comment: There are free sage servers online, see [sagemath](http://www.sagemath.org).

Comment: In particular, https://cloud.sagemath.com/ account required, but you can run completely in-browser, no install needed.

Comment: Sage worked for me, the ratio is $337856166410008691221935300852944795396687361668980788
$

Comment: The online calculator for magma allows long text  http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks! I was going through the documentation because I didn't know how to compute a division with it haha.

Comment: I got 337856166410008691221935300852944795396687361668980788 too, using [reduce](http://reduce-algebra.com/). The numbers given are small enough for reduce, though for larger numbers I find [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) better (interpreted or compiled). Ultimately Haskell relies on big number packages written in C or C++, I believe (though don't remember their names), but I have usually found easier to install Haskell in my computer than C++, and it works fast.(But it requires some learning as its syntax is not similar to C++, or Python or Java, though basic arithmetic is not a problem.)

Comment: If you use C++, you could also use mpfr.

Comment: In sage, I just wrote $a=\langle\text{first number}\rangle$, $b=\langle\text{second number}\rangle$ and they typed $a/b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something that is just cut-and-paste: Alpern's [*Factorization using the Elliptic Curve Method*](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM)

It easily performs your $a/b$, then factors the quotient,

$$337856166410008691221935300852944795396687361668980788$$

and also says your $101$-digit divisor $b$ is composite.

Answer (score 1):

If you have acces to a Unix machine, then you probably have `bc` installed:

```
% bc
a=9069623170135106601720652920891221901050326166164088662904293991480616103992855701624463727487162247889904330833818932916941082247238731419301804839603756
b=26844628193432396109627227465177021833123967807981281489587894114558469448102682070257837402824170487
a/b
a%b
```

gives you these quotient and remainder:

```
337856166410008691221935300852944795396687361668980788
0
```

Almost the same program works with Python. Just use

```
print(a/b)
print(a%b)
```

Comment: That's nice, I wasn't aware that Bash and Python managed large numbers naturally. Thanks!